# RecyclerView : exclude a view from being refreshed

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I have a `RecyclerView` that shows YouTube videos thumbnails. I want to exclude these thumbnails from being refreshed when the `notifyItemChanged()` method is called for some position.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Video> videos;

    private Animation loadingRotation;

    public VideosAdapter(Context context, List<Video> videos) {
        this.videos= videos;

        loadingRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.refresh_btn);
        loadingRotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (parent instanceof RecyclerView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            VideoItemLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.video_item_layout,
                    parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(binding);

            return holder;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something is wrong with the RecyclerView");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //views that would update

        //I want to exclude this:

        holder.b.thumbnail.startAnimation(loadingRotation);
        holder.b.thumbnail.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                                                YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videos.get(position));
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                        youTubeThumbnailView.clearAnimation();
                        youTubeThumbnailView.setBackground(null);
                        youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                                                 YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                        youTubeThumbnailView.clearAnimation();
                        youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                                                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ads.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        VideoItemLayoutBinding b;

        ViewHolder(@NotNull VideoItemLayoutBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.b = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

The thumbnail declaration in the **video_item_layout.xml**

```
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loading_thumbnail"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_thumbnail_description"/>
```

I used an animation (rotating progress bar) to be played while the thumbnail is being loaded, and it stops when the thumbnail is ready.

I tried to put `thumbnail.initialize()` in the `onCreateViewHolder()` and in the `ViewHolder()` constructor, but still nothing, the thumbnail is always being reloaded when I call `notifyItemChanged()`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should add a boolean value to your list objects, initially it will be false then first time after your thumbnail is loaded it will be true, then you can put any check as per your requirement

Comment: @SahilKumar No that didn't work. The idea may seem right, but I think there is a problem with the `YoutubeThumbnailView` itself. I can't find a way to lock the view to the loaded thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of these methods of Recycle View

```
notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)
notifyItemChanged(int position)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)
```

As per your requirements, It won't refresh the whole recycle view items but the selected ones. For more details you can refer to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

About payload, it is very clear from the documentation that

> Client can optionally pass a payload for partial change. These
>   payloads will be merged and may be passed to adapter's
>   onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List) if the item is already
>   represented by a ViewHolder and it will be rebound to the same
>   ViewHolder. A notifyItemRangeChanged() with null payload will clear
>   all existing payloads on that item and prevent future payload until
>   onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List) is called. Adapter should not
>   assume that the payload will always be passed to onBindViewHolder(),
>   e.g. when the view is not attached, the payload will be simply
>   dropped.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this `Object payload`, I don't get the docs.

Comment: No, that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can override the notifyItemChanged() method as below

```
@Override
public void notifyItemChanged(int position){
if(position!=THE_POSITION_WHERE_YOU_DONT_WANTED_TO_REFRESH){
super.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
}
```

Comment: You are not getting my problem. I want to not refresh only the Thumbnail when `notifyItemChanged()` called, not exclude the whole item. The Thumbnail is an element, among others that I want to refresh, from the item_layout.